# Is there an Admin/Management SDK that works on both Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, admin, data-management

I have been curious about whether there is a admin SDK that can be implemented in both android and iOS which will help keep tract of metrics and analytics of an app - Similar to Google admin SDK.

Or would it make more sense to build an in-house infrastructure to collect and manage this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [google analytics for ios](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) and [google analytics for android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).

Comment: Thanks @indramurari, will look into it. Do you have experience with AWS Mobile?

Comment: @DavidDeBacker I have not worked on AWS Mobile. But it's very simple to use as my coleauge is working on it